# Can Flume use ElasticSearch with Amazon Elastic Search Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, flume, flume-ng

Originally I was trying to setup Flume to write to S3 to my AWS setup like this:

```
aws.sinks.channel1.type = hdfs
aws.sinks.channel1.hdfs.path=s3n://<id>:<secretkey>/<bucketname>
aws.sinks.channel1.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
aws.sinks.channel1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
aws.sinks.channel1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
aws.sinks.channel1.hdfs.rollSize = 67108864
aws.sinks.channel1.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
aws.sinks.channel1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
```

However, it has occurred to me that I do not have access to "bucketname".
Our ElasticSearch service on Amazon does not expose the file system layer.

Is there any way to use the elasticsearch sink or some kind of http sink in order to push flume information through to something like Kibana on AWS?

For clarity, I want to push ElasticSearch to Amazon. The sources I have are avro & http, and do not come from Amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=683536

> When speaking about AWS ElasticSearch Service, native transport
>   protocol is not supported. REST API over HTTP protocol is supported
>   currently.

Bummer!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your sources are, but Beats are the ELK stack alternative to a Flume agent. And Logstash and/or Kafka are the persistent channels

Flume would be reading your hdfs-site.xml for the S3 access keys, so that's where it would get your keys from

You can install ES-Hadoop to get Elastic to read data from Hadoop (and the S3 filesystem). I haven't tried this personally, but I know the library exists for that reason.

If you want to use Flume, you could use the syslog or netcat Flume sinks to write to Logstash (if you have it), which can index to Elasticsearch. There's also a WebHDFS plug in for Logstash, I believe.

Another solution includes using NiFi or Streamsets instead of Flume

Comment: I'm using Flume, and I'm not reading from S3. I need a sink to push to S3. The sources I have are http & avro

Comment: Do you have Kafka? https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/s3_connector.html

Comment: Okay, well, you will at least need Logstash. Read over it's documentation to see what inputs it accepts. Then Elastic as an output. Your Elasticsearch data is not using S3, anyway. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/cloud-aws-best-practices.html